# Remove Punctuation in a field in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql

I have a field in table  in Oracle SQL developer that I need to remove all punctuations in a specific field. The table name is "punctuationtest"
and the function that I tried does not work, I got error with the @InputString
Here is the function that I tried : any ideas and suggestions will be helpful thanks

```
         CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_RemovePunctuation
           (
           @InputString VARCHAR(500)
           )
           RETURNS VARCHAR(500)
             AS
            BEGIN
            SELECT
             @InputString = REPLACE(@InputString, P.Symbol, '')
             FROM 
            Punctuationtest P

          RETURN @InputString
           END
            GO
```

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer is a client application used to access multiple RDBMS (but primarily Oracle databases); it is **NOT** a database. Your code looks like it is for Microsoft SQL Server and not Oracle. Please [edit] your question to tag the database you are connecting to (and not the client application).

Comment: **Never say “I got an error” without telling us what the error is.**  Cut & paste the exact error so that we can see what it says.  If we can't see the error, we can't tell what the problem is.  It's like taking your car to the mechanic and saying "The car makes a noise" but not telling what the noise is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

"Oracle SQL Developer" is a tool you use to establish connection to a database and do *something*. Which database is it? Usually, it is **Oracle**. But, then again, code you posted certainly is NOT Oracle - hence error you got (at least, I think so).

If your database really is Oracle, then you could try with such a regular expression (see line #6):

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'abc,!23' from dual union all
  3     select '?xyz,.'  from dual
  4    )
  5  select col,
  6         regexp_replace(col, '[[:punct:]]') result
  7  from test;

COL     RESULT
------- ----------------------------
abc,!23 abc23
?xyz,.  xyz

SQL>
```

---

Or, as you want to update a table, you'd

```
update your_table set 
  that_column = regexp_replace(that_column, '[[:punct:]]');
```

Comment: If I need to remove spaces in the field is the query listed below correct?   update your_table set 
  that_column = regexp_replace(that_column, '[[:space:]]');

Comment: If you want to remove spaces, then use `replace(that_column, ' ')`. No need for regular expressions in that case.